# Mysql - Query does not work on the server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This query doesn't work for me on the server else it's working correctly on Phpmyadmin at local-host :

```
SELECT * FROM op_theme_certification
AS t 
INNER JOIN op_category_module AS c 
ON t.cat_mod_id = c.cat_mod_id, 
(SELECT cat_mod_id, MAX(date_expiration) AS max_date FROM op_theme_certification 
GROUP BY cat_mod_id) AS b 
WHERE t.doc_id = '1' 
AND t.cat_mod_id = b.cat_mod_id 
AND t.date_expiration = b.max_date
```

any can help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which OS you are using as local and which is on server?

Comment: i'm using wamp (mysql 5.5.20)

Comment: On server i have mysql 5.5.35

Comment: Running with Phpmyadmin or with PHP code on the server?  If the latter can you post the PHP code running the query?

Comment: **"phpMyAdmin"** itself runs on server Sir! Please be more precise!!

Comment: Make sure error display is enabled in your php.ini or your script, or look into Apache's error log.

Comment: i tested my code in my mysql client for server version (using mysql workbench) but with the same result as website is displaying (nothing) and without any error

Comment: Its working fine for me now, thanks a lot for every body

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks correct, I've seen answers in the past that for some reason frown on using the "AS" clause for aliasing the tables, and also "AS" column names.  I would start there.  Second, I notice you are using a mix of join vs comma/where join.  The following is an alternative to what you have now.

```
SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
      op_theme_certification t
         INNER JOIN op_category_module c
            ON t.cat_mod_id = c.cat_mod_id
         INNER JOIN 
            ( SELECT 
                    cat_mod_id, 
                    MAX(date_expiration) max_date 
                 FROM 
                    op_theme_certification
                 GROUP BY 
                    cat_mod_id) b
            ON t.cat_mod_id = b.cat_mod_id 
           AND t.date_expiration = b.max_date
   WHERE 
      t.doc_id = '1'
```

I would definitely have a compound index on your op_theme_certification on (cat_mod_id, date_expiration).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, buts it's doesn't function for me your adaptation code.
i think it's relied with the sub_query ` ( SELECT 
                    cat_mod_id, 
                    MAX(date_expiration) max_date 
                 FROM 
                    op_theme_certification
                 GROUP BY 
                    cat_mod_id) b`

Comment: my problem its on :  AND t.date_expiration = b.max_date

Comment: SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
      op_theme_certification t
         INNER JOIN op_category_module c
            ON t.cat_mod_id = c.cat_mod_id
         INNER JOIN 
            ( SELECT 
                    cat_mod_id, 
                    MAX(date_expiration) max_date 
                 FROM 
                    op_theme_certification
                 GROUP BY 
                    cat_mod_id) b
            ON t.cat_mod_id = b.cat_mod_id 
           AND t.date_expiration = b.max_date
AND doc_id = '1'
   WHERE 
      t.doc_id = '1'